# PHP max_input_vars delaying server response time

Tags: centos, php, apache-http-server

Hi im using a CentOS vps with 6gigs of dedicated ram im hosting WordPress on that a little while ago i got an error saying that max_input_vars have exceeded so i have edited my php.ini and made it to 3000 although my max input vars are 1200 there is delay in server response time (around 2-4 seconds) what can i do reduce this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How sure you are about the cause of this delay? Is it the time your client spends in sending the data in the HTTP request? Is it the time PHP spends in processing? Or is it the download of the response from the server?

Sorry for asking questions instead of replying. But I think the first step here is detecting where the delay is. I would recommend you to use Firebug o Chrome developer tools. Open the Network tab and make a request. Then select the first row in the results table (the one which represents the request, because you will see other rows for CSS files, JS files, images, etc). And check the timing data which usually is divided into sending/waiting/receiving stages. The waiting stage is related to the server processing speed, the other two are related to both server and client bandwidth.

Further debugging should be done after that, depending on where the delay seems to be.

Comment: i have installed firebug it says 3.58s waiting and reviving is 1.36s

Comment: Well, almost four seconds for processing. The problem seems to be on the PHP side. Is it a custom PHP development or are you running Wordpress. If it's your code, you can use getrusage() or other functions to measure processing time of each part of your application. If you have Wordpress you could look for a debugging plugin.

Comment: its a wordpress installation i have a huge theme running on this it has more options i more options i choose the slower its becoming when i revert the theme to defaults the site is at jet speed. I have monitored the cpu usage when i access the website and on one cpu it says 35% and the rest are at 0%

Comment: I had a problem with a Wordpress theme we bought some months ago. In that case I had to extend the memory limit for get it working and it's hosted over a powerful server. My opinion is that some Wordpress theme developers don't optimize their work. Try switching back to default theme and test again. I'm pretty sure the issue is going to disappear. If that happens you can contact the theme developer in order to fix the problem.

Comment: hi can i do something to distribute the load on to all the cpu's reducing processing time ?

Comment: Assuming you are using Apache default scheme over a Unix-like system, your server is spawning a child Apache process for every request. At operating system level, processes are being distributed among installed CPUs already. Unless there is something really wrong in the server. Furthermore, default Apache MPM is multithreaded thus I guess it's being distributed at that level too. [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/perf-tuning.html) / Do you think this high CPU usage is reasonable for a Wordpress theme?

Comment: Yes sir it is because of the theme i have now started building my own custom CMS instead of wasting my money on unwanted high CPU resources for some crappy theme.

Comment: Now I see this issue is more common than I though before. Sites selling themes should include some sort of typical CPU usage for the themes. Otherwise there is no way to know until you pay and install the theme. Be sure you use a [Wordpress child-theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) so you won't loose your changes when you update the original theme!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14165/discussion-between-drk-com-ar-and-maniteja)